# showing extra information in an html5 meter element; nesting elements within the meter?

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, css

I am using the meter element to show a score between 1 & 10, and in the newest webkit browsers, it looks fantastic.

I would now like to show the average score, as well. While it's useful to know that my submission received a 6 out of 10, it would be even more useful to know that the average for this magazine so far is a 5.

Unfortunately, the [slew of available attributes for the meter tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_meter.asp) does not include "average".

I want to show a simple vertical line at the average value. I thought perhaps I could put a span or a div inside the meter, make it display: block, and give it a 100% height, a 50% width, and a border-right. Unfortunately, Chrome 11 doesn't even allow me to nest block elements within the meter, my preliminary investigations indicate.

I'd be willing to use JS to display the vertical line if I had to (when I originally envisioned this feature I thought I'd be using entirely JS), but the meter tag is so delightful that I refuse to *not* use it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trick may be placing a span after the meter tag, shifting it to the left using some arithmetic

```
<meter id="m" value="2" min="0" max="10">somevalue</meter>
<span id="average" 
      style="border-left:1px solid black;width:1px;margin-left:-50px">
</span>
```

aritmetic could be something like:

```
var average = [somevalue, say 0.45];
document.getElementById('average').style['margin-left'] = 
 (Math.floor((average-1)*document.getElementById('m').offsetWidth))+'px'
```

Comment: margin-left is not a valid property name. It has to be marginLeft :)

Comment: @john_doe: yep, you're right. Could've used style['margin-left'] also, by the way.

Comment: This works! I used jQuery, so it looks a little different, but the idea worked. I've actually just added a `data-average="6"` attribute to the `meter`, and then use jQuery to insert a span after each meter with a data-average attribute. Here's the jQuery: $('meter[data-average]').after(function(){
      return '<span class="average-score" style="margin-left: -' +
              (1 - $(this).attr('data-average')/10) * $(this).width() +
              'px"></span>';
    });